# SVG - make inner part of rectangle completely transparent

Tags: svg, d3.js

Is there a possibility to make a part of svg rect transparent? f.x. it has width 100px, and between 40 and 70 px it is transparent. Problem is - the central part should be really transparent and show elements below, it should be not filled with  background color like mask.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use a clip path, see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking

Comment: thanks, Lars, I've tried but I need inversion on clipping http://jsfiddle.net/0g6pj8dm/ Yellow part must be blue,i.e. bottom layer blue rectangle must be visible in the center, and blue must be yellow.

Comment: Well define the clip path appropriately then http://jsfiddle.net/0g6pj8dm/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`clipPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking) to define which parts of your SVG should be transparent.

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0g6pj8dm/1/).